# Why is Mirror's Edge crashing just after the logo splash screens?

Tags: technical-issues, mirrors-edge, vmware-fusion

I got Mirror's Edge on Steam, but I'm unable to play the game. As soon as the logos finish, the game crashes.

Resolution Attempts:

- Tried relaunching Mirror's Edge. No change in behavior.
- Tried relaunching Steam. No change in behavior.
- Tried verifying integrity of game cache. No change in behavior.
- Tried rebooting. No change in behavior.
- Tried installing latest PhysX. No change in behavior.
- Tried manually setting ResX, ResY in TdEngine.ini to my screen's actual resolution. No change in behavior.
- Tried setting PhysXEnabled to False in TdEngine.ini. No change in behavior.

System:

- Latest Mirror's Edge
- PhysX 9.13.1220
- Latest Steam client
- Windows 8 Professional x64
- VMware Fusion 6
- Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks
- 13" mid-2013 MacBook Air, Haswell Intel Core i7, 8GB RAM, 256 GB SSD

Comment: I've had the same. +1 for the good explaining

Comment: So you are playing this inside a virtual machine? Why not use Wine instead? Seems to run flawlessly: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=9046

Comment: @Assylum Does Wine work on Mac OS?

Comment: Wine should work on Mac OS. http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX

Comment: In my experience, Wine is much harder to use than VMware. But I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion from a [thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2127437) on the Steam Users' Forums:

copy

```
Mirror's Edge\Binaries\PhysXLocal\PhysXLoader.dll
```

to

```
Mirror's Edge\Binaries\PhysXLoader.dll
```